# Force Jenkins to run only one pipeline job and put rest all in queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to build only one project at a time in entire jenkins server. I have tried Jenkins throttle concurrent plugin and lockable resource plugin but no luck. As lockable resource plugin doesn't give me option to lock in pipeline job.

I have 3 Jenkins pipeline jobs (job have pipeline script):

```
JOB1
JOB2
JOB3
```

which has some common thing at beginning of the job (clearing content).

Running one by one manually doesn't have any problem if job completed but if JOB1 is building and JOB2 starts in between then it interrupts to JOB1 and build fails for JOB1.

Even when I start jobs using CLI, you never know which job might be running. So, I'm looking for solution to block JOBY if JOBX is running (X, Y can be 1,2 or 3) and allow only one job to run in entire Jenkins server. Like I said, throttle concurrent plugin gives customization option only for respective job instead of for multiple jobs?

Can anyone suggest some solution for multi pipeline jobs block to run only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin)

In configuration of JOBY check "Block build if certain jobs are running".

Put JOBX name in Blocking Jobs text area, each job on new line.

Note, you can also use regex to define in single line jobs having the same prefix but ending with different numbers.